# Mapbox directions - check distance from routes

Tags: distance, mapbox, marker, directions

I'm using mapbox direction for draw route between two points. I need to check distance from this route to some other marker on map.
code for directions. Thanks.

```
            var directions = L.mapbox.directions({
            profile: 'mapbox.driving' 
        });

        directions.setOrigin(L.latLng(lat1, long1)); 
        directions.setDestination(L.latLng(lat2 , long2));   
        directions.query(); 

        var directionsLayer = L.mapbox.directions.layer(directions).addTo(map); 
        var directionsRoutesControl = L.mapbox.directions.routesControl('routes', directions)
            .addTo(map)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the response from the directions query the [Route object](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#retrieve-directions).  The response is an array of *n* routes.  And in the response is `distance: Number indicating the distance traveled in meters`

You can also use the [Mapbox Command Line Interface](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-cli-py) to see the responses from the directions query.  This particular query gives a response of `"distance": 642`

```
mapbox-cli>   mapbox directions "[-79.4460, 43.6656]" "[-79.4434, 43.6602]"
```